# Prevent all items in array from rerendering when only some items change in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm implementing some autocomplete in my app. When there is new text in an  I get http data as a string[] in . When I enter D DIOE and DAKT is rendered as an item. If I enter DI then, the DIOE rerenders. This is exactly what I want to prevent, because it looks ugly if the item disappears and reappears for a blink.

How does one prevent the whole array rerendering in my context, if only some items change?

The render

```
...
<nav>
{similars && similars.map((val, index) => {
  return <Similar key={`similar-${val}-link`} similar={val} className={index == this.state.currentSimilarIndex ? transactionStyle.active : ''} onClick={() => this.clickSimilar(val)} />
})}
</nav>
...
```

An item for render

```
class Similar extends React.PureComponent<Similar.Props, Similar.State> {
  render(): JSX.Element {
    const { similar, className, onClick } = this.props

    return (
      <a key={`similar-${similar}-link`} className={className} onClick={onClick()} tabIndex={1}>
        {similar}
      </a>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `shouldComponentUpdate` could be helpful.

Comment: Wouldnt that mean the other items, which actually got changed, wouldn't rerender?

Comment: If the *other items* are separate components, the rerender event will work separately.

Comment: No change for me.

Comment: Hum, I believed that react did a smart computation on render, eg : items with existing key would only be updated, not deleted then inserted, are you sure your key is unique ?

Comment: Every similar var is different, yep.